# Which client for MimeKit.MimeMessage?

Tags: .net, email, mimekit

I have a C# project with
`<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>`.

I can create a message, `MimeKit.MimeMessage` class, but I don't know how to send it.
`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` requires a MailMessage (System.Net.Mail).
I'm trying to use *MimeKit 2.10.1* or *MimeKitLite 2.10.1* NuGet packages but **I can't find a client that can send the MimeMessage**!
The documentation ([Get Started](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Getting-Started.htm)) has hundreds a line of code to create any sort of message but not a single line that shows hot to send it.

All the examples I find online are using a non specified "client".
On another post it uses the **MailKit** client to send the *MimeKit* message but I don't think the *MailKit* library is mandatory (to send a message).

Which client should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I wrote MimeKit, I had intended for it to be usable from any email client library (or application) that wanted to use it, free from being forced to use any one particular client library.

I had not intended to write MailKit at the time.

I eventually wrote MailKit because I decided that the best way to convince Free/Open Source email client libraries that they should use MimeKit and how powerful MimeKit was, was to write a proof-of-concept client library showcasing its abilities.

Apparently my proof-of-concept MailKit library turned out so good, all of the other Free/Open Source client libraries seemed to have died out and now MailKit is the defacto client library for .NET (and so good, that even Microsoft now endorses it as the preferred solution for .NET Core in the documentation for [System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-5.0) in their **Remarks** section).

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the insightful info. One thing (maybe just a curiosity at this point).
MimeKit without a "dedicated" client has any real usage? I mean, if I compare the MimeMessage to the PDF file format, it will not be "usable" without a "dedicated" Reader (from Adobe or any other provider).
About MimeMessage, now I know you created it to be "usable from any email client library" but that means that you didn't have any tool to use it initially?
So you created the MailKit library, also if only for test initially ? 
Is this correct or I still miss the point?

Comment: MimeKit on its own is still useful as a way of parsing/writing MIME formatted messages. A more apt comparison would be that a library to read and write PDF files is still useful even without an HttpClient to upload or download the PDF files from the web :-)